# Ruby - why assign parameters to instance variables?

Tags: ruby, instance-variables

Sometimes I see code like

```
class Thing
  def self.add_em(a,b)
    a+b
  end
end
```

and sometimes I see

```
class Thing
  def self.add_em(a,b)
    @a=a
    @b=b
    @a+@b
  end
end
```

When/Why should I use the `@` instance variables instead of just using the parameters as passed?

I believe that one reason is if you want to use those variables in any other method then instance variables will be available and local, parameter based variables will not.  However I frequently see @ variables being used even though the variables are not being used in any other method.

So I see the pattern of
@a=a
@b=b
at the start of method for all parameters passed in being used a lot but I'm not clear exactly why if they are just used on that method.  Is it just a convention in case they are used in other methods?

Comment: You know the answers,which you wrote are correct. But it depends how you are using OOP design in you codebase.

Comment: I came upon this question because I answered another question of yours that got closed, deleted, undeleted. This one, too, seems completely reasonable and not "almost entirely based on opinions". Anyway, I agree with the answers you received. I'd only add that I've mostly seen the @a=a @b=b pattern in the `initialize` method, where you almost always want to save the arguments for later use.

Answer (score 2):

As you correctly realized, it does not make sense to define instance variables unless they are used in another method. If instance variables are used but are not called in any other method, then that code is probably not written by a good programmer.

But note that sometimes, method definitions are not obvious at first look. For example, if there is

```
class Thing
  attr_reader :a
end
```

then there actually is a method that uses `@a`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that they did it because they had plans to reference the arguments as instance variables. If not they failed the YAGNI (you aint gonna need it principle). If they changed their minds half way through (which has been known to happen...), they they forgot to tidy up.

Comment: It sounds like you have particular code in mind. Do you?

Comment: Moi? Put some code I turned out not to need? "Forgot" to tidy up. How very dare you sir? :)